# How to send/share data between an Electron app and UWP app

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp, electron

I have a usecase where I need to be able to send data (images and maybe some json metadata) from an electron app to a UWP (gamebar) app.

The obvious answer to this would seem to be writing data to a local file on disc from Electron, and reading it from the UWP app. The issue I'm having there is that even with `<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>` enabled in my UWP app, the user would have to explicitly enable file access for this app in their Windows settings in order for my UWP app to be able to read a file from an arbitrary location on disc.

Is there a way to have inter-process communication between the apps to get around this issue?

Comment: Have you checked other ways that I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to save the file into the Document library which is enabled by default as long as you added the `documentsLibrary` capability in the manifest file.

```
       StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
       StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("paris.png");
```

If you don't want to use file system to do the IPC, you might need to check other ways here: [UWP-ipc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication)

Comment: This still requires explicit permissions to be enabled by the user

Comment: @John `DocumentsLibrary` is enabled by default unless user manually disabled it. As I mentioned in my answer, you could check other ways about IPC for UWP here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I understand now. It seems like a weird place to draw the line at allowing access to the documents folder by default but not other locations.